# Error while sending PDF as attachment using SMTP

Tags: python, pdf, mime, smtplib

While running the below piece of python script to send pdf attachment using SMTP, encountered SMTPDataError exception. I am able to send text or image files using the below code with the same sender and to the same recipient. The pdf file size is hardly 1 MB.

```
import smtplib
import email
import email.mime
import email.mime.application

from_email = "XXXX@gmail.com"
from_passwd = ""
to_email = "abc@gmail.com"

message = email.mime.Multipart.MIMEMultipart('mixed')
message['Subject'] = 'Test_run'
message['From'] = from_email
message['To'] = to_email

text_part = email.mime.Text.MIMEText("""This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>

""",'html')
message.attach(text_part)

filename1 = "some_doc.pdf"
fp = open(filename1 , 'rb')
attach_part = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fp.read(),"pdf")
fp.close()

attach_part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename = "some_doc.pdf")
message.attach(attach_part)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
server.starttls()
server.login(from_email,from_passwd)
server.sendmail(from_email,to_email,message.as_string())

server.close()
```

The error message encountered

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 746, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, '5.7.1 The user or domain that you are sending to (or from) has a policy that\n5.7.1 prohibited the mail that you sent. Please contact your domain\n5.7.1 administrator for further details. For more information, please visit\n5.7.1  https://support.google.com/a/answer/172179 66sm37804549pfx.29 - gsmtp')
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/172179

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message and following its instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending a PDF to a different recipient in a different domain? Or sending a similarly-sized image to this same recipient?

Sounds like this domain might not allow pdf attachments, for whatever reason...

Comment: I am able to send image of greater size to the same recipient. To a different recipient, did not encounter any exception, but got "message not delivered" in my sent items.

Comment: is there any account settings to be configured??